# What the argument "{limit: 25}" means in the jQuery .load() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

```
$("#element").load(url, {limit: 25}, function(responseText,textStatus,req){

    //Do stuff

}
```

I would like to know what "{limit: 25}" means. I tried Google and here, but never found. Even in the jQuery documents. Does anyone knows?

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter to [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is the parameters that will be sent to the remote resource. Since `load()` used `GET` request the parameters will be sent as a query string.

If you look at the resource request using the browser developer tools, the request will be `someurl?limit=25`. It looks like a paging based page where the client is request the server to sent back 25 records.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I copied this code thinking that it's some type of time limit or something like that. Since I'm just loading a simple php request, I can delete it, right?

Comment: @WagnerKobayashi yes... if it is not used by your server side code then you can delete it